# How to send Metrics via Scrapy to Prometheus?

Tags: python, scrapy, grafana, metrics, prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus.

I need too send the numbers of scraped items to **Prometheus** and show them on a graph in **Grafana**.

I installed [**Prometheus**](https://prometheus.io/download/), [**Scrapy-Prometheus**](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-prometheus/), and **[Grafana](https://grafana.com/)** .

In Scrapy setting I add

```
STATS_CLASS = 'scrapy_prometheus.PrometheusStatsCollector'
# Prometheus pushgateway host
PROMETHEUS_PUSHGATEWAY = 'http://0.0.0.0:9090'   
# Metric name prefix
PROMETHEUS_METRIC_PREFIX = 'scrapy_prometheus'   
# Timeout for pushing metrics to pushgateway
PROMETHEUS_PUSH_TIMEOUT = 5  
# Method to use when pushing metrics
PROMETHEUS_PUSH_METHOD = 'POST'  # default
PROMETHEUS_SUPPRESS_TYPE_CHECK = False
# job label value, applied to all metrics.
PROMETHEUS_JOB = 'scrapy' 
PROMETHEUS_GROUPING_KEY = {'instance': 'localhost'}
```

I configurate the setting of Grafana like this

[image]

In [**Documentation**](https://github.com/sashgorokhov/scrapy_prometheus#how-metrics-are-created) we have

> stat foo: 67 whill produce metric
>
> scrapy_prometheus_foo{instance="...",job="scrapy",spider="..."} 67

My question is how can I send the number of scraped items as metrics to Prometheus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the docs it seems that `scrapy-prometheus` just sends all stats in:

```
<prefix><stats name with / replaced by _>
```

Default prefix is `scrapy_prometheus` and the stat you are looking for items scraped is `item_scraped_count`, so you should be looking for **`scrapy_prometheus_item_scraped_count`** stat and it should be sent by default.